# Facebook login get country value from JSONObject

Tags: android, facebook, json, country

So I need to implement login using social media like `facebook` and its all working except i cannot get country value from the location `JSON`

```
public void facebookLogin() {
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(mLoginView.getContext());
    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions((Activity) mLoginView.getContext(),Arrays.asList("email","user_location"));


    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callBackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {
            Log.i("LoginFacebook","Sucess");
            Log.i("",""+loginResult.getRecentlyGrantedPermissions());
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                            Log.v("LoginActivity", response.toString());

                            // Application code
                            try {
                                String email = object.getString("email");
                                String location = object.getString("location{location{country}}");

                                Log.i("",location);
                                Log.i("",email);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                Log.i("","ERRROROROROR");
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender,location{location{country}}");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
}
```

`graphObject:`

> {"id":"****************","name":"********","email":"******@gmail.com","gender":"male","location":{"location":{"country":"Portugal"},"id":"***********"}}, error: null}

```
08-16 17:00:10.807 19813-19813/care.petable_android3.petable_android W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for location{location{country}}
```

Comment: Location is your `JSONObject` so get first Location `JSONObject` then get to Location & country.

Comment: Something like this ?  `try {
                                    String email = object.getString("email");
                                    JSONObject locObject = object.getJSONObject("location");

                                    String location = locObject.getString("country");

                                    Log.i("",location);
                                    
                                }`

Comment: try on this way`JSONObject obj_loc = new JSONObject(object.getString("location"));`    
`String location = locObject.getString(‌​"country");`
`Log.i("",location);`

Comment: Thank you i managed to get like this `String email = object.getString("email");
                                    JSONObject locObject = object.getJSONObject("location");
                                    JSONObject loc2Object = locObject.getJSONObject("location");

                                    String location = loc2Object.getString("country");`

Comment: @HardikParmar becaus its like "location":{"location":{"country":"Portugal"}

Comment: Ya its good hear object inside object that why